# DateTime value has issues in Visual Studio 2019 16.11.34 when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, visual-studio-2019

I use Visual Studio 2019 16.11.34 version.
I have a problem about datetime values when debugging process.

[image]

`nowDate` is shown above. Normally, it is shown as a full date. Since I cannot see the exact date when I hover over it, I have to type the exact date in the watch section and look.

[image]

I hope I explained the problem fully. I tried to change the settings, but it does not work.

Comment: I believe you have pinned the Day filed of datetime in your watch. Expand the nowDate object in your watch and unpin that field.

Comment: Expand `nowDate` in that watch window and look at the `Day` property. Does it have a pin icon against it? If so, untick that.

Answer (score 2):

You have pinned `Day` property, unpin it and you will see full date.

[image]